# Uninstall Oracle Java JRE where misexec reports "this is only valid for products that are currently installed"

Tags: windows, java, configuration-management, software

I have several end users where Oracle Java JRE 1.8.0_xxx is installed but the automation to use the UninstallString via msiexec /X is failing by saying the product isn't installed. On these machines it does indeed not show up in Programs and Features, but the installation is there. The binaries and executables are all in C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_xxx\ and the registry is still holding a GUID for the product. What other way is there to uninstall this?

Editing to add the verbose logging of the failed uninstall

=== Verbose logging started: 11/30/2023  12:29:11  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.10011.00  Calling process: C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe ===

MSI (c) (A0:30) [12:29:11:782]: Font created.  Charset: Req=0, Ret=0, Font: Req=MS Shell Dlg, Ret=MS Shell Dlg
MSI (c) (A0:30) [12:29:11:782]: Font created.  Charset: Req=0, Ret=0, Font: Req=MS Shell Dlg, Ret=MS Shell Dlg
MSI (c) (A0:4C) [12:29:11:802]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (A0:4C) [12:29:11:802]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (A0:4C) [12:29:11:802]: ******* RunEngine:
******* Product: {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F64180311F0}

******* Action:

  ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (A0:4C) [12:29:11:803]: Client-side and UI is none or basic: Running entire install on the server.
MSI (c) (A0:4C) [12:29:11:803]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (A0:4C) [12:29:11:924]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (A0:4C) [12:29:11:924]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (A0:4C) [12:29:11:929]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (20:90) [12:29:11:959]: Running installation inside multi-package transaction {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F64180311F0}
MSI (s) (20:90) [12:29:11:959]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (s) (20:90) [12:29:11:974]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (s) (20:90) [12:29:11:974]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (s) (20:90) [12:29:11:974]: ******* RunEngine:
******* Product: {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F64180311F0}
******* Action: 
******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (s) (20:90) [12:29:11:974]: Machine policy value 'DisableUserInstalls' is 0
MSI (s) (20:90) [12:29:11:975]: MainEngineThread is returning 1605
MSI (s) (20:90) [12:29:11:985]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (20:90) [12:29:11:985]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (20:90) [12:29:11:985]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (20:90) [12:29:11:985]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (20:90) [12:29:11:986]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (20:90) [12:29:11:987]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (A0:4C) [12:29:11:988]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (A0:4C) [12:29:11:989]: MainEngineThread is returning 1605
=== Verbose logging stopped: 11/30/2023  12:29:11 ===

Answer (score 0):

This could mean that there was a failed, aborted, or partial uninstallation.

You should try running msiexec.exe with the maximum verbose logging and examine the log for the registry keys and values that were checked and are missing.

Use the following PS command to confirm the product code:

`get-wmiobject Win32_Product | Format-Table IdentifyingNumber, Name`

And run the uninstall:

`msiexec.exe /x "{guid}" /l*v c:\path\to.log`

---

Update: try the following from the *native command prompt*:

`START /WAIT /MIN WMIC product where "Name LIKE 'Java 8%%'" call uninstall /nointeractive`

https://forums.ivanti.com/s/question/0D54O00007Cc0qdSAB/cant-silently-uninstall-java-jre-8u311-x64-via-the-uninstallstring?language=en_US

Comment: Added the logging to the question. Nothing jumps out at me.

Comment: You may want to try the suggestion here that worked for someone else.  https://forums.ivanti.com/s/question/0D54O00007Cc0qdSAB/cant-silently-uninstall-java-jre-8u311-x64-via-the-uninstallstring?language=en_US

Comment: I ran this wmic command now, it hung for about 2 min indicating it was doing something, then finished with no change to the JRE installed, and no sort of output one way or the other.

Comment: It's because the underlying wmic query also has no results for a product name like Java%. Neither wmic or msiexec have record this is installed, even though I'm staring at the installation files in Program Files